# XSLT union or execute foreach for 2 different nodes

Tags: xslt

How do we union or execute foreach between 2 xpath simulatenously

```
<Country>
<States>
    <State>
        <name>1</name>
        <id>California</id>
    </State>
    <State>
        <name>2</name>
        <id>Texas</id>
    </State>
    <State>
        <name>3</name>
        <id>New York</id>
    </State>
</States>
<Cities>
    <City>
        <name>3</name>
        <id>SFO</id>
    </City>
    <City>
        <name>4</name>
        <id>SAN DIEGO</id>
    </City>
    <City>
        <name>5</name>
        <id>ORLANDO</id>
    </City>
</Cities>
```

I want to loop through both country and state and get the name and id.

Answer (score 6):

**Use the XPath union operator**: `|`

```
/*/States/State | /*/Cities/City
```

This selects all `State` elements that are children of all `State` elements that are children of the top element of the XML document **and also** all `City` elements that are children of all `Cities` elements that are children of the top element of the XML document.

**In XSLT one can specify a template that matches more than one type of node, using again ... the XPath union ('|') operator** as part of the match pattern:

`<xsl:template match=""City | State">`

This template rule matches any `City` or `State` element.

**Finally**, here is a complete transformation that outputs the name and id of any `City` or `State`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="City | State">
     <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Country>
    <States>
        <State>
            <name>1</name>
            <id>California</id>
        </State>
        <State>
            <name>2</name>
            <id>Texas</id>
        </State>
        <State>
            <name>3</name>
            <id>New York</id>
        </State>
    </States>
    <Cities>
        <City>
            <name>3</name>
            <id>SFO</id>
        </City>
        <City>
            <name>4</name>
            <id>SAN DIEGO</id>
        </City>
        <City>
            <name>5</name>
            <id>ORLANDO</id>
        </City>
    </Cities>
</Country>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<name>1</name>
<id>California</id>
<name>2</name>
<id>Texas</id>
<name>3</name>
<id>New York</id>
<name>3</name>
<id>SFO</id>
<name>4</name>
<id>SAN DIEGO</id>
<name>5</name>
<id>ORLANDO</id>
```